# Create 2 separated taxonomy pages with views

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms, views

I have 2 nodes type "Article" and "Page", I also have 2 taxonomy for each node type are "Taxo 1" for Article and taxo 2 for "Page", is there any way to create 2 seperated views so,

```
with "taxonomy/term/%" for Article I have grid views
```

and

```
"taxonomy/term/%" for "Page" I have "Unformated List",
```

beside 2 node types have alot of different fields.
Is there any way to handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really appreciate the Taxonomy Views Integrator module for things like that. https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi

Answer (score 0):

Your template file name should be like this -> taxonomy-term--tid.tpl.php 
[Source](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656)